# Leibniz Integral Rule applied n-times

Tags: leibniz-integral-rule

I was trying to come up with a generalization of the Leibniz Integral Rule
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_a^xf(x,t) \; dt\right) = f(x,x) + \int_a^x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} 
 f(x,t) \; dt
$$
and arrived at the following and i am not sure if it is correct
$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(\int_a^xf(x,t) \; dt\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f^{(k)}(x,x)+\int_a^x \frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n} 
 f(x,t) \; dt
$$
Can someone maybe confirm or refute this?

Comment: What is this $f^{(k)}(x,x)$? First calculate $\frac d{dx}f(x,x).$

Comment: the k-th derivative with respect to x of f(x,x)

Comment: I thought that $\frac{d}{dx} (f(x,x) +  \int_a^x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t) dt) = f'(x,x) + f(x,x) +   \int_a^x \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} f(x,t) dt)$ and tried to follow the pattern from there

Comment: I have doubt in question and comment in member $f(x,x)$ - how you get it?

Comment: I found this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule right above the "General form: differentiation under the integral sign" section

Comment: I'm not asking about the formula itself, but about your conclusions from it - how do you get a term $f(x,x)$ in your conclusions?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} f(x,x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial 1}(x,x)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial 2}(x,x)=f'_1(x,x)+f'_2(x,x)$

Comment: I thought f(x,x) can  be seen as a function in a single variable as it will only contain x and no other variables

Comment: Yes but your notation $f^{(k)}(x,x)$ for its k-th derivative is erroneous. Your function of a single variable is a composite of $f$ with $x\mapsto(x,x)$. To differentiate it you must apply the chain rule. zkutch gave you the result for $k=1$ (which was the question in my initial comment).

Answer (score 1):

After computing the first few derivatives you can immediately see, that the pattern is the following:
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(\int_a^xf(x,t) dt\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k+1}\frac{\partial^{n-1} f}{\partial x^{n-1-k}\partial t^k}(x,x) + \int_a^x\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial x^n}f(x,t)dt$$
Trivially in the case $n=1$ this reduces to the known formula. Now for the induction step:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}\left(\int_a^xf(x,t) dt\right) =& \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k+1}\frac{\partial^{n-1} f}{\partial x^{n-1-k}\partial t^k}(x,x) + \int_a^x\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial x^n}f(x,t)dt\right)\\
=& \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k+1}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial^{n-1} f}{\partial x^{n-1-k}\partial t^k}(x,x) + \frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial x^n}f(x,t)dt\\
=& \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k+1}\left(\frac{\partial^{n} f}{\partial x^{n-k}\partial t^k}(x,x)+\frac{\partial^{n} f}{\partial x^{n-1-k}\partial t^{k+1}}(x,x)\right)\\
& + \frac{\partial^{n} f}{\partial x^{n}}(x,x)+\int_a^x\frac{\partial ^{n+1}}{\partial x^{n+1}}f(x,t)dt
\end{align*}
So it remains to show that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k+1}\left(\frac{\partial^{n} f}{\partial x^{n-k}\partial t^k}(x,x)+\frac{\partial^{n} f}{\partial x^{n-1-k}\partial t^{k+1}}(x,x)\right) + \frac{\partial^{n} f}{\partial x^{n}}(x,x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k+1}\frac{\partial^{n} f}{\partial x^{n-k}\partial t^k}(x,x)
\end{align*}
For shorter notation, we set $$c_{n,k}:=\frac{\partial^{n} f}{\partial x^{n-k}\partial t^k}$$
so that above equation becomes
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k+1}\left(c_{n,k}+c_{n,k+1}\right) + c_{n,0} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k+1}c_{n,k}
\end{align*}
This is now pure combinatorics:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k+1}\left(c_{n,k}+c_{n,k+1}\right) + c_{n,0} =& \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k+1}c_{n,k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k+1}c_{n,k+1} + c_{n,0}\\
=& \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k+1}c_{n,k}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}c_{n,k} + c_{n,0}\\
=& \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k+1}c_{n,k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}c_{n,k}\\
=& \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\binom{n}{k+1}+\binom{n}{k}\right)c_{n,k}+c_{n,n}\\
=&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}c_{n,k}+c_{n,n}\\
=&\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k+1}c_{n,k}.
\end{align*}
Thus by induction the above identity holds.

Comment: Thank you very much!! The only thing i don't understand is where the $\partial t$ comes from before $f(x,x)$. I thought $f(x,x)$ doesn't contain $t$.

Comment: $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}f(x,x)$ means $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)\big|_{t=x}$. I guess it would be written more accurately as $\frac{\partial }{\partial e_2}f(x,x)$ where $e_2$ denotes the second standard basis vector. It appears because this is a $\frac{df}{dx}$ total derivative

Answer (score 0):

Here is another derivation of the formula obtained in @StiftungWarentest's answer.

For the sake of simplicity, assume that $f(x, t)$ is smooth and compactly supported on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then by writing $\theta(t) = \mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(t)$ for the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), the $n$th weak derivative of the integral is computed as

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d} x^n} \left[ \int_{a}^{x} f(x, t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right]
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d} x^n} \left[ \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x, t) \theta(x-t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right] \\
&= \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n} [ f(x, t) \theta(x-t) ] \, \mathrm{d}t \tag{1} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \int_{a}^{\infty} \left[\frac{\partial^{n-k} f}{\partial x^{n-k}} (x, t) \right] \theta^{(k)} (x-t) \, \mathrm{d}t. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

- In $\text{(1)}$, we utilized the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).
- In $\text{(2)}$, we invoked the [Leibniz product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule).

On the other hand, for any $n \geq 0$ and for any compactly supported smooth $\varphi$ on $\mathbb{R}$, a similar computation shows that

$$ \int_{a}^{\infty} \varphi(t)\theta^{(n)}(x-t) \, \mathrm{d}t
= \begin{cases}
\varphi^{(n-1)}(x), & n \geq 1, \\[0.5em]
\displaystyle \int_{a}^{x} \varphi(t) \, \mathrm{d}t, & n = 0.
\end{cases} $$

So by fixing $x$ and applying this identity to $\text{(2)}$, we obtain

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d} x^n} \left[ \int_{a}^{x} f(x, t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right]
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{\partial^{n-1} f}{\partial x^{n-k}\partial t^{k-1}} (x, x) + \int_{a}^{x} \frac{\partial^{n} f}{\partial x^{n}} (x, t) \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}

Finally, although the above equality holds *a priori* in weak derivative sense, both sides are bona-fide smooth functions for any $n$. Consequently, the equality holds in the usual derivative sense, yielding the correct formula for the $n$th derivative of the integral.